# How to create a wxpython program for switch that update all the time according to the switch state?

Tags: python, wxpython, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I has create a simple python program for switch.
This simple program work fine.
The code is below:

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 from time import sleep
 GPIO.setwarnings(False)
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)

 count = 0
 flag = 0
 while True:
     input = GPIO.input(40)
     if ((not flag) and input):
         flag = input
         count += 1
         print "--------------------"
         print "Button is pressed"
         print "Flag = ", flag
         print "Count = ", count
         sleep(0.05)

     elif ((not input) and flag):
         flag = input
         count += 1
         print "--------------------"
         print "Button is debounce"
         print "Flag = ", flag
         print "Count = ", count
         sleep(0.05)

 GPIO.cleanup()
```

But when I try to create a wxPython Program to display the output
the program work for the first click on the button but when I release the button the output on wxPython program stay the same except the time updated that stop when I release the button and continue when I press the push button.
The wxPython program is as below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)

count = 0
flag = 0
button = "None"
input = GPIO.input(40)

global update_time
update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y     %H:%M:%S')

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "The wxPython module is required to run this program."

class OnOffApp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (500, 200), title = 'ON / OFF Status')
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Button Status : {}'.format(button))
        self.label1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label1.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label1, (1,0), (1,2), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Flag Status : {}'.format(flag))
        self.label2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label2.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label2, (2,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Count Status : {}'.format(count))
        self.label3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label3.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label3, (3,0), (1,4), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label4 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Time Updated : {}'.format(update_time))
        self.label4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label4.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label4, (4,0), (1,5), wx.EXPAND)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(50)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def on_timer(self,event):
        global update_time
        update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y    %H:%M:%S')

        count = 0
        flag = 0                                  
        input = GPIO.input(40)
        if ((not flag) and input):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Pressed'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Pressed")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))

        elif ((not input) and flag):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Debounce'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Debounce")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Rs = wx.App()
    OnOffApp_wx(None, -1, 'ON / OFF Status')
    Rs.MainLoop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Help me to make the wxPython program work as when I press the button the state of input and flag change to 1 and count is increase by one. When I release the button the state of input and flag change to 0 and count is increase by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `on_timer` you are re-setting both `count` and `flag` to zero every 50 milliseconds.
Either pass them as variables into the function or for you purposes, it will be easier to simply declare them as `global` within the `on_timer` function.
So:

```
count = 0
flag = 0
```

becomes:

```
global count, flag
```